# How to set up flag in WinGhci, Haskell

Tags: windows, haskell

I have problem with `n+k` pattern.

I want to enable it, but i don't know how.

I have added `{-# LANGUAGE NPlusKPatterns #-}` at the beggining of my `.hs` file, but it didn't work.

Also I try typping in my ghci console `-NPlusKPatterns` but is just gives me errors.

Comment: AndrewC is correct. I would, however, note that use of n+k patterns is generally discouraged--see the [Haskell' reasoning](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/NoNPlusKPatterns), and there is much more discussion to be found on the mailing list archives. I would avoid them without a very good reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to type

```
:set -XNPlusKPatterns
```

in ghci to enable them.

For completeness I'll point out that if you load ghci from the command prompt instead of running winghci, you can load it with `ghci -XNPlusKPatterns` instead of interactively doing `:set -XNPlusKPatterns`.

You can check whether it's working by defining an n+k pattern interactively. Here's an example session:

```
Prelude> let fact 0 = 1; fact (n+1) = (n+1)*fact n in fact 5
<interactive>:8:23: Parse error in pattern: n + 1

Prelude> :set -XNPlusKPatterns
Prelude> let fact 0 = 1; fact (n+1) = (n+1)*fact n in fact 5
120
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I type it in, nothing showed up. Then I type just :set and "options currently set: none." thats showed up.

Comment: Try typing `let fact 0 = 1; fact (n+1) = (n+1)*fact n in fact 5`

Comment: It works, and shows up 120. Here is my code: foldn h c 0 = c ;
foldn h c (succ n) = h (foldn h c n). When I change succ n to n + 1 everything works just fine, thanks!

Comment: Why not write it as `foldn h c n = h (foldn h c (n-1))` ? You wouldn't need n+k patterns at all.